# big64 - sum() on a vector of NA produces odd results

Tags: r, bit64

When using `big64` package, summing a vector of `NAs` to another vector of integers yields an inaccurate result. Depending on whether the `NA` vector is summed first or last, the results will be either `0` or twice the correct answer, respectively.

Notice that converting the `NA` vector away from integer64 will remove the issue.

However, when experimenting with other small values in place of y, the results were awfully strange. 
For example:

```
40 + 35 = 75    but
35 + 40 = 80
```

Any thoughts as to what is going on?

EXAMPLE:

```
  library(bit64)

  x <- as.integer64(c(20, 20))
  y <- as.integer64(c(NA, NA))

  sum(y, x, na.rm=TRUE)
  # integer64
  # [1] 80   # <~~~ Twice the correct value

  sum(x, y, na.rm=TRUE)
  # integer64
  # [1] 0   # <~~~~ Incorrect 0.  Should be 40. 

  ## Removing the NAs does not help. 
  y <- y[!is.na(y)]

  ## A vector of 0's gives the same issue
  y <- as.integer64(c(0, 0))

  ## Same results
  sum(y, x, na.rm=TRUE)
  # integer64
  # [1] 80

  sum(x, y, na.rm=TRUE)
  # integer64
  # [1] 0

  ## Converting to numeric does away with the issue (but is not a viable workaround, for obvious reasons)
  y <- as.numeric(y)

  sum(y, x, na.rm=TRUE)
  # [1] 1.97626e-322

  sum.integer64(y, x, na.rm=TRUE)
  # integer64
  # [1] 40

  sum(x, y, na.rm=TRUE)
  # integer64
  # [1] 40
```

Give `y` a single value, and the results are also very out of place

```
  y <- as.integer64(c(35, NA, NA))
  sum.integer64(x, if (!all(is.na(y))) removeNA(y), na.rm=TRUE)
  sum.integer64(x, y[[1]], na.rm=TRUE)
  sum.integer64(y[[1]], x, na.rm=TRUE)

  ## No NA's present
  sum.integer64(as.integer64(35), x)
  # integer64
  # [1] 80
  sum.integer64(x, as.integer64(35))
  # integer64
  # [1] 70
```

Comment: Though `sum(c(x,y),na.rm=TRUE)` gets `40`

Comment: @akrun, that might be a nice workaround.   Although still a very unexpected result and it leaves one curious what is going on

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but an exploration. Hope it might help you.

From the `sum.integer64` function of the `bit64` package:

```
function (..., na.rm = FALSE) 
{
    l <- list(...)
    ret <- double(1)
    if (length(l) == 1) {
        .Call("sum_integer64", l[[1]], na.rm, ret)
        oldClass(ret) <- "integer64"
        ret
    }
    else {
        ret <- sapply(l, function(e) {
            if (is.integer64(e)) {
                .Call("sum_integer64", e, na.rm, ret)
                ret
            }
            else {
                as.integer64(sum(e, na.rm = na.rm))
            }
        })
        oldClass(ret) <- "integer64"
        sum(ret, na.rm = na.rm)
    }
}
```

Here is your example:

```
library(bit64)
x <- as.integer64(c(20, 20))
y <- as.integer64(c(NA, NA))

na.rm <- TRUE
l <- list(y, x)
ret <- double(1)
ret
#[1] 0

# We use the sapply function as in the function:
ret <- sapply(l, function(e) { .Call("sum_integer64", e, na.rm, ret) })
oldClass(ret) <- "integer64"
ret
#integer64
#[1] 40 40      <-- twice the value "40"
sum(ret, na.rm = na.rm)
# integer64
#[1] 80         <-- twice the expected value, as you said
```

Here we decompose the calculation, for each vector:

```
ret <- double(1)
ret2 <- NULL
ret2[1] <- .Call("sum_integer64", y, na.rm, ret)
ret2[2] <- .Call("sum_integer64", x, na.rm, ret)
oldClass(ret2) <- "integer64"
ret2
#integer64
#[1] 0  40      <-- only once the value "40", and "0" because of NaNs
sum(ret2, na.rm = na.rm)
#integer64
#[1] 40         <- expected value
```